# IONIC/cordova, make phone call in IOS

Tags: ios, cordova

I have found a thread in ionic on this topic: http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/making-phone-call-from-app-href-tel-123/1968/11.

It mentions the whitelist plugin:
https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist

So I try to add these code in the config.xml, but it still can not work.

```
<access origin="tel:*" launch-external="yes" />
<access origin="mailto:*" launch-external="yes" >

<allow-intent href="tel:*" />
```

**HTML**:

```
<a href="tel: 110">call</a>
```

**Error**:

> 2015-07-03 00:21:16.231 myParking[27167:1006045] Failed to load
>   webpage with error: The URL can’t be shown

I try to use another plugin, but it still can not work.

https://github.com/Rohfosho/CordovaCallNumberPlugin

**HTML**:

```
<span ng-click="onDail($index)">call</span>
```

**JS**:

```
var onSuccess = function(){
    console.log("success");
}

var onError = function(){
    console.log("fail");
}

$scope.onDail = function(index){
    window.plugins.CallNumber.callNumber(onSuccess, onError, $scope.ParkingRecords[index].number);
}
```

**Error**:

> 2015-07-03 00:24:09.620 myParking[27308:1007392] fail

So how can I make this work?

ionic version: **1.4.3**
cordova version: **5.0.0**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have resolved this issue. In my environment(ionic version: 1.4.3 cordova version: 5.0.0), I don't need to add any Plugin or revising the configuration file as ozhanli mentioned. The  directive can work as expected. So why I ask this problem? Because I test my program in the simulator, which doesn't support the phone call, message and so on. After deploying my program to a physical device, the  directive works.

So if you want to make a phone call in IONIC(ionic version: 1.4.3 cordova version: 5.0.0) , just add this code to make it work:

```
<a href="tel: 110">call</a>
```

Notice: Test it in physical device, not in simulator.

Answer (score 12):

I try it in `a` tag it worked on android:

First add cordova-plugin-whitelist

```
cordova add plugin cordova-plugin-whitelist
```

Then add following lines in *config.xml*

```
<access origin="tel:*" launch-external="yes" />
<allow-intent href="tel:*" />
```

Finally in `a` tag  use line below

```
<a href="tel:555 555 5555" target="_blank">
    <i class="fa fa-phone"></i>
</a>
```

Comment: This should be for old version IONIC and cordova. Now, it is not necessary to download the Plugin and revise the config.xml. See my answer for details. Anyway, TNX for your answer.

Comment: I'm fairly new to ionic, but to add to the last comment, the above fix helped get it working on ionic 1.7.16 (from ionic --version).

Comment: Is this code works on IOS Device. this code works on android but doesn't work on IOS