# Phone Number not clickable on IOS ionic

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, phone-number

I am using `Ionic 1` and on my app I am using a phone number. If the user clicks the phone number then I want the number to open in the call window so that user can directly call that number. It is perfectly working on android. But unfortunately it is not working on IOS. Following codes emphasizes what I have tried so far -

On my HTML file -

```
<a href="tel:*******">******</a>
<a target="_blank" ng-href="tel:*******">******</a>   //also tried this
```

On my Config.xml file -

```
<access origin="tel:*" launch-external="yes" />
<access origin="mailto:*" launch-external="yes" >

<allow-intent href="tel:*" />
```

I have tried all the solutions suggested on the below link including changing the config file, using the cordova call number plugin and the codes. But I can not get it to work on IOS. I have tested on IOS 6s device with IOS version 10.

[Stackoverflow solution one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31202870/ionic-cordova-make-phone-call-in-ios)

[Stackoverflow solution two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19639663/cordova-trying-to-dial-telephone-number)

[Ionic Forum solution](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/making-phone-call-from-app-href-tel-123/1968)

I can not understand what I am doing wrong. Thanks in advance for any kind of help.

Comment: What version of Cordova you're running? I guess that this is a trouble from Safari browser.

Comment: I have used the latest version of cordova call number plugin.